# JTree nodes' rendering and font changes

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jtree

I have a problem with rendering nodes in JTree. When node's font is changed and node's text gets wider that way then node's text is cut and end of text replaced with dots. 
How to tell the JTree then that it should widen area to render tho whole node.

Thank you for help

Comment: How are you changing the node font? `tree.setFont(..)`? Or are you using a renderer?

Comment: Is this change of nodes running in a non event dispatch thread? If so you have to call this code via SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom renderer and set to the component (JLabel) something like this

```
final Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize(); 
label.setMinimumSize(size); 
label.setPreferredSize(size);
```

or just set text like this

```
setText("<html>" +valueText+"</html>")
```

Comment: I tried the HTML solution but my string contains blank spaces and it only shows the first word

Comment: Yea this answer is not appropriate. The issue is to do with JTree caching sizes of the label, and this is not how you override that (by implementing a custom renderer...)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the trigger of the font change happens under the feet of the tree: internally, the ui delegate does lots of size caching which must be updated on any change which effects the cached sizes. That's done automatically on changes to the treeModel, to relevant expansion state and some visual changes to the tree itself.

So the basic question is: what triggers the change of the font? If it's some change of the model/nodes, the model implementation is incorrect in not firing an appropriate TreeModelEvent, the obvious solution would be to fix that :-) If it's something outside the model, the solution depends on the details of your context, nothing generally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

### Size caching

The JTree uses a [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) to render nodes. The [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) is the same renderer for all OSs, so the differnt lookings are inside [ComponentUIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI.html). JTree uses by default a JLabel to paint nodes, so its the JLabel's size wo guides us to cut the text using `...`.

Lets make a short excourse: Swing has differen LookAndFeels for different Operation Systems, they are detached from the components in UI-Classes like the [BasicLabelUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.html) (and this is the source of your problem). [BasicLabelUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.html) caches the size of the label to prevent recalculation if no changes has made. So [BasicLabelUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.html) did not clear the cache of theese old size values. [BasicLabelUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.html) do clear the cache if he gets informed about any changes.

The question is, why does the [BasicLabelUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.html) did not get informed about changes? Well, if you modify/expand/rename the Tree programatically you must tell the ComponentUI to drop that cache!

You lucky, you do not need to write much code because a genius already wrote something for you, the creators of the TreeUI-class **Rob Davis** and **Scott Violet** wrote startEditingAtPath and stopEditing.

### Example

```
TreeUI ui = tree.getUI();
for (TreePath treePath : selectionPaths) {
    ui.startEditingAtPath(tree, treePath);
}
tree.setSelectionPaths(selectionPaths);
tree.expandPath(expandPaths.getSelectionPath());
ui.stopEditing(layer);
```

Answer (score -1):

Call your `TreeModel`'s `reload()`

Comment: I mean, how does one know if it is intended for application usage? I had the same problem as the question starter and for me `updateUI` works perfectly, no indication its not intended for application usage since its a public method...

Comment: a) read its api doc b) nothing perfect with accidentally covering the underlying problem (most probably missing/incorrect notification on model change) by a side effect of a randomly called method

Comment: a) the api doc doesnt say updateUI is not intended for application usage though b) have been using my software for 20hours straight now and not had a single glitch

Comment: a) The api doc states exactly, what the method is meant for: _Resets the UI property to a value from the current look and feel_ - no change in ui-property, no calling of the method. b) 20 _hrs_ - cool, that's a real stress test ;-) couldn't resist kidding, no offence meant! You are completely free to insist on your errors (as mentioned earlier, most probably are missing/incorrect change notification from the model, repeating for emphasis). You are not free to on spreading hacks needed due to your errors - of course you can, but not without downvoting and strong emphasis that it's **wrong**